# relation between norms of two vectors

Tags: normed-spaces

Can we say that;
if the $l_1$-norm of an arbitrary vector $a$ is smaller that $l_1$-norm of $b$ ($||a||_1 \le ||b||_1$) then the $l_2$-norm of $a$ is smaller than $l_2$-norm of $b$
($||a||_2 \le ||b||_2$) as well?

Thanks

Comment: Take, e.g. in $\Bbb R^4$, $b=(1/3,1/3,1/3,1/3)$ and $a=(1,0,0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\Bbb R^2$, $a=(1,3)$ and $b=(2,2)$. They have the same $l^1$ norm, but their $l^2$-norm is different.

Comment: Have you computed the $l^2$ norms?