# Relation between L2 norm and L1 norm of two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

For two given $N\times 1$ vectors $x,y$ , if $||x||_2\geq ||y||_2$, can I say that $||x||_1\geq ||y||_1$? If not give an example. Converse of this question has been asked [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247442/relation-between-norms-of-two-vectors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample: $y = \frac{2}{3}[1 \quad 1]^T$, $x = [1 \quad 0]^T$.